# How to add list data into table data on one click by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want when someone writes list in textarea and press "Add Values" then the every line list should be added to the first table column(Please refer image). I mean first line data from list should be added to first column line data and so on... I have no idea about how I can do this by JavaScript share me your solutions.

**[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quQO7.jpg)**

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfwm3o1d/)**

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<textarea rows="10" cols="50">First
Second
Third
Fourth
Fifth
  </textarea><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Values</button><br><br>


<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Sr No</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
</center>
</body>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  
}
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {

  const values = document.querySelector('#input')
  .value.trim().split('\n');
  
  const table = document.querySelector('#myTable');
  
  for (const value of values)
    table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${value}</td><td></td><td></td></tr>`;
  
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<center>

<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="input">First
Second
Third
Fourth
Fifth
</textarea><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Values</button><br><br>


<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Sr No</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>  
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: This runs out td's when there is more input than TR. Probably better to check for that, or to remove the old tbody and restart creating one with fresh tr td lines.

Comment: But I want my 5 data should be added to first column! Your code adding it into rows

Comment: I fixed it, check it now. @santosh

Answer (score 0):

This function will works

```js
function myFunction() {
     var arrayOfRows = document.getElementById("input").value.split("\n");
     var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
     for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
         row.cells[0].innerHTML=arrayOfRows[i-1]
      }
 }
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<center>

<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="input">First
Second
Third
Fourth
Fifth
</textarea><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Values</button><br><br>


<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Sr No</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
</center>
```